# Dev environment from react component

Tags: reactjs, components, storybook

I am creating on library component in React.

The component will be imported into another project using `import ... from ...`.

So, the question is very simple.

Which testing environment for local development is the best way to use? I don't want to use webpack, because it's not "app" its only single component.

I read about storybook, but I thank its to "big" for one component.

Is there any other environment for the local development of component?

Now, after any change, I need to build my component and run in another project to test.

Comment: Perhaps you could treat this component as a library. If it should be a public one, just use NPM. If it is a private one, you could define it as a dependency in your package.json anyway, just give the path to git repo instead. Then the question transforms into "How I publish a React component as NPM library", which is a different one and shouldn't be hard to google your way towards the end result.

Answer (score 0):

Webpack is still needed beacause you want a minified and optimized build of your code in `/dist`.

Storybook is useful only when you have to build a Docs section for your component.

I suggest you to rely on this article for a correct pipeline in order to build a react component (and publish it on NPM)

ref: https://medium.com/@BrodaNoel/how-to-create-a-react-component-and-publish-it-in-npm-668ad7d363ce

Answer (score 0):

I would use create-react-app. It really speeds up development, after you can extract your tested code anyways.